# filtering divs in jQuery and hiding them based on a custom data attribute tag

Tags: jquery, sorting, attributes, ternary-operator

I'm several hours into building a simple sortable search results for an online merchant site. The way it works, is that a html template is fetched of the search page, while the search is carried out with ajax. the json data is retrieved, and the div elements are then created. I have already completed the `sort`,`per`, and `direction` sorts, but now i'm stuck on the `filter` sort and i really have no idea where to even begin on this last one.

the last sort function needs to iterate over each div, checking the selected attribute for a 1 or a 0. if the attribute is 0, the `hide` class needs to be toggled for the div.

My question is:

- how to access current selected div inside of `each()`
- how to check if the datatarget is equal to 0.
  hide it if it is 0, or
- how to continue to next iteration of `each()` if it is not.

**a brief pseudocode of what i'm trying to achieve:**

```
$('div.item').each(function(){
 datartarget = (datatarget == 0) ? currentdiv.hide() : datatarget;
});
```

**Here's my full `jQuery` code:**

```
$(function(){
    var last_selector = null;
    last_selector = $('.filter , .sort, .per, .direction').click(function(){
        var clname = this.className;
        var direction = $('#direction > dd.active > a').attr('data-target');
        $('.sub-nav.'+clname+'').find('dd.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var datatarget = $(this).attr('data-target');
        if(clname == 'sort')
        {
            $('div.item').tsort({order:direction,attr: datatarget+'-data'});
            last_selector = datatarget;
        }
        if(clname == 'filter')
        {
            last_selector = (last_selector == null) ? last_selector : $('#sort dd.active > a').attr('data-target');
            $('div.item').each(function(){

                //have no idea where to start )-:
            })
        }
        if(clname == 'per')
        {
            last_selector = (last_selector == null) ? last_selector : $('#sort dd.active > a').attr('data-target');
            var item_count = $('div.item').length; 
            if(item_count > datatarget)
            {
                while (item_count > datatarget) {
                    $('div.item:last-child').toggleClass('hide');
                    item_count = $('div.item').length;
                }
            }
            if(item_count < datatarget)
            {
                $('div.item.hide').toggleClass('hide');
                while (item_count > datatarget) {
                    $('div.item:last-child').toggleClass('hide');
                    item_count = $('div.item').length;
                }
            }
        }
        if(clname == 'direction')
        {
            direction = $(this).attr('data-target');
            datatarget = (last_selector == null) ? last_selector : 'price';
            $('div.item').tsort({order:direction,attr: datatarget+'-data'});
        }
        return last_selector;
    });
});
```

**and the html**

**the dropdown selection divs(provides the `datatarget` for the click functions):**

```
<a data-dropdown="direction" class="button dropdown">Direction Order</a>
<dl id="direction" data-dropdown-content class="sub-nav direction f-dropdown content">
  <dt><strong>Direction:</strong></dt>
  <dd class="active"><a class="direction" data-target="desc">Down</a></dd>
  <dd><a class="direction" data-target="asc">Up</a></dd>
</dl> 

<a data-dropdown="filter-by" class="button dropdown">Filter Results</a>
<dl id="filter-by" data-dropdown-content class="sub-nav filter f-dropdown content">
  <dt><strong>Filter Results:</strong></dt>
  <dd class="active"><a class="filter" data-target="new">Newest</a></dd>
  <dd><a class="filter" data-target="endsoon">Ending Soon</a></dd>
  <dd><a class="filter" data-target="reserve">No Reserve</a></dd>
  <dd><a class="filter" data-target="buyitnow">Buy It Now</a></dd>
  <dd><a class="filter" data-target="all">All</a></dd>
</dl> 

<a data-dropdown="sort-by" class="button dropdown">Sort Results</a>
<dl id="sort-by" data-dropdown-content class="sub-nav sort f-dropdown content">
  <dt><strong>Sort By:</strong></dt>
  <dd class="active"><a class="sort" data-target="end">End Time</a></dd>
  <dd><a class="sort" data-target="price">Price</a></dd>
  <dd><a class="sort" data-target="seller">Seller Reputation</a></dd>
</dl>  

<a data-dropdown="results-per" class="button dropdown">Results Per Page</a>
<dl id="results-per" data-dropdown-content class="sub-nav per f-dropdown content">
  <dt><strong>Per Page:</strong></dt>
  <dd class="active"><a class="per" data-target="100">100</a></dd>
  <dd><a class="per" data-target="75">75</a></dd>
  <dd><a class="per" data-target="50">50</a></dd>
  <dd><a class="per" data-target="25">25</a></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Your ternary operators seem to be backwards. The part after `?` is returned when the test is true.

Comment: @Barmar how can i access the current position inside of each? i think that is what is confusing me. how to get the current div selector inside of `each()`, ie the current position in the array of divs.

Comment: @Barmar, wouldn't this already be assigned to the selector of the click event though? i'm still somewhat of a beginner with js, so forgive my lack of knowledge please. would `this` have changed to the current position of the `each()` function?

Comment: Inside `.each()`, it rebinds `this` to the current element of the iteration.

Comment: Oh, ok. thank you. if that solves it will you submit it as an answer so i can award you the solved

Comment: You can also use the parameters to the iteration function. `$(selector).each(function(index, element) {...}`.

Comment: If it were a well-written question, you wouldn't have to clarify so much in the comments. I don't even understand what the pseudo-code has to do with the full jQuery code that you posted below it. There's no `.each()` in the full code.

Comment: I can't figure out what the question is, I can't write an answer.

Comment: Well, basically it was how to complete the functionality of my sort. Someday a noob might come along wondering how to multi sort divs without datatables and he may find this post helpful. Since it hasn't gotten any upvotes, i will soon be banned but oh well.

Comment: I don't see any sorting code in the question. I see calls to a method `.tsort()`, I guess that's the jQuery Tiny Sort plugin?

Comment: @Barmar yes its the plugin. this is like a multisort type of deal. you can sort based on attribute, change the # results per page, filter based on  attribute, and change search direction. My question was confusing. i will carefully reword and explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of barmar, i answered my own question.

i was confused because i didn't realize that `this` would be rebound inside of `each()`.

the following accomplishes my goal, of changing the current filter, by first unhiding any hidden elements, then applying the new filter.

```
if(clname == 'filter')
{
    $('div.item.hide').toggleClass('hide');
    last_selector = (last_selector == null) ? last_selector : $('#sort dd.active > a').attr('data-target');
    $('div.item').each(function(){
        ($(this).attr(datatarget+'-data') == 0) ? $(this).hide() : false;
    });
}
```

Of course, this only addresses the basic functionality. i still have to modify it to maintain the results per page rules.