# Control display of a div based on data-* attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am showing articles in a list of divs. Each div has a data attribute that contains the status of the article.

```
<div id="article_1" data-status="read"> ... </div>
<div id="article_2" data-status="unread"> ... </div>
```

There is a button that toggles views to show "All Articles" or only "Unread" articles.

My toggle function looks like this, which is working fine:

```
function toggle(status) {
    if (status == 'all') {
         $('*').filter(function() {
            if ($(this).data('status') == "read") {
                $(this)[0].style.display = 'block';
            }
         });  
    }
    else {
         $('*').filter(function() {
            if ($(this).data('status') == "read") {
                $(this)[0].style.display = 'none';
            }
         });
    }
}
```

***Question***: Is there a better (faster, efficient) way to select divs with `data-status` attribute and based on the status toggle the view?

Ref:

[1] [Jquery select all elements that have $jquery.data()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499998/jquery-select-all-elements-that-have-jquery-data)

[2] [Show/hide multiple divs based on a value in their attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33675418/show-hide-multiple-divs-based-on-a-value-in-their-attribute)

[3] [filtering divs in jQuery and hiding them based on a custom data attribute tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652337/filtering-divs-in-jquery-and-hiding-them-based-on-a-custom-data-attribute-tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just select on the `data-status` attribute itself:

```js
function toggle(status) {
    if (status == 'all') {
      $('[data-status=read]').css('display', 'block');
    }
    else {
      $('[data-status=read]').css('display', 'none');
    }
}

toggle('unread');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="article_1" data-status="read"> read </div>
<div id="article_2" data-status="unread"> unread </div>
```

Comment: Perfect !! Plain and simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can go very simple here:

```
function toggle(status) {
  if (status == 'all') {
    $('*[data-status="read"]').show();
  } else {
    $('*[data-status="read"]').hide();
  }
}
```

Hope that helps